# Can't upgrade to JRE 1.6 from 1.4.2

Tags: windows-xp, java, jre

For the life of me I can't get my JRE upgraded. I've ran JDK6u21 and nothing, re-installed and nothing, tried JRE6u21 and still

java version "1.4.2_06"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.4.2_06-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.4.2_06-b03, mixed mode)

Any suggestions? Can I force to 1.6? The 1.6 directory is in my path, don't even know where 1.4 is.

Comment: you should tell us what operating system you run.

Comment: It was for an XPSP3 OS. The problem was there were still stale references in the System variables 'Path', even though the User variables in PATH were OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't using JRE 1.4.2, uninstall it. You didn't mention which operating system you are using, so there may be some catch related to the OS which needs special attention.
For example in new versions of Ubuntu you have to run

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

to configure java.

If 1.6.21 is in your path, and java -version in terminal reports what you wrote, check your path. 1.4.2 is in it before 1.6.21. The obvious solution is to remove old version from path or to place new before old.

Comment: Ahhh checked the 'PATH' user variables and everything looked ok - but apparently the 'Path' system variables still contained references to the old installation. Changed it and everything looks good. Thanks for the help, it was for an XPSP3 installation.